# Using mb_substr still breaks accent character at the end

Tags: php, utf-8

**Logic**: I am getting username from DB and if it is greater than 30 in length then i show 30 characters with "..." appended at the end.
Code is

```
$username = htmlspecialchars($username);
if(mb_strlen($username, 'utf-8')>30){
    $username_trimmed = mb_substr($username, 0, 30, 'utf-8').'...';
}
```

and in my navivation I am just printing this `username`

```
<class="userName">Hello, <?php echo $username_trimmed; ?>
```

My encoding in set as `utf-8`, and `mbstring` extension is enabled in php.

**Output** of above code : It still breaks the accent character `É` because it is multi-byte character and it is getting cut the in the middle.
Actual word is `MARCHÉS` and output is:
[image: Erroneous output]

**Question** what am I missing? `mb_substr` should not consider it as a single character and should not stop it from breaking in the middle as it does?

Comment: _“what am i missing? ”_ – that your input value for the function is not what you think it is.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks your hint did helped me understanding that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your string is actually `"&Eacute;"`, not `"É"`. `mb_substr` handles your characters just fine, it does *not* handle HTML entities. Don't store HTML entities in your database, store actual Unicode characters. At the very least, decode from HTML entities to actual characters using [`html_entity_decode($str, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8')`](http://php.net/html_entity_decode) before applying `mb_substr` (and then apply `htmlspecialchars` again afterwards to preserve HTML syntax).

Comment: That's it using both of them as i was already using html_entity_decode, just need to add htmlspecialchars

Answer (score 1):

use htmlspecialchars after mb_substr, not before. htmlspecialchars converts the characters into HTML entities. You wouldn't want an html entity to get cut in the middle.

Comment: using htmlspecialchars  after mb_substr converts & into html entity &amp.
**Output**: Hello, Aliaaaaaa test (MF: MARCH&amp;...

Comment: & should get converted into &amp; for it to be displayed as &.
If you see &amp; on the website, that means that it was already an html entity. If special characters are already HTML-encoded, then &amp; becomes &amp;amp; and the user sees &amp;
So, if the string is already using HTML entities, you won't need to use htmlspecialchars

Comment: P.S.: if the original strings sometimes contain html entities and sometimes they don't, use $username = htmlspecialchars_decode before using mb_substr and after that use htmlspecialchars

Comment: well thank you for the tip here. But that breaking in the middle issue persists.

Comment: Have you also removed htmlspecialchars at the beginning? When I wrote "use htmlspecialchars after mb_substr" I meant instead of before mb_substr, not in addition.

Comment: Yes that did the trick i.e using htmlspecialchars at the begining.